# $\lim_{r\to 0}\int_C \log(1-e^{2i\pi z})dz=0$ for quarter circle $C$ from $ri$ to $r$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, analysis

Consider the quarter circle from $z=ri$ to $z=r$ for $r>0$. 
Denote this quarter circle by $C$.

I would like to show that $\lim_{r\to 0}\int_C \log(1-e^{2i\pi z})dz=0. $

How can I evaluate this limit? My rough idea is that $\log(1-e^{2i\pi z}) \sim \log r$ and the length of $C \sim r$, so we use $r\log r \to 0$, however, I can't formalize this idea. I would greatly appreciate a formal argument for proving this.

Answer (score 2):

Since, by definition, $$
\log\left(1-e^{2i\pi z}\right)=\log\left|1-e^{2i\pi z}\right|+i\arg\left(1-e^{2i\pi z}\right),
$$
we have $$
\int_C \log\left(1-e^{2i\pi z}\right)dz=\int_C \log\left|1-e^{2i\pi z}\right|dz+i\int_C \arg\left(1-e^{2i\pi z}\right)dz.$$
Recall that$$
\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{e^{2i\pi z}-1}{z}=2i\pi,$$
then we have$$
\pi r<\left|1-e^{2i\pi z}\right|<4\pi r$$
for $z$ with $|z|=r$ sufficiently small. This leads to
$$
\log(\pi r)\int_C |dz|<\left|\int_C \log\left|1-e^{2i\pi z}\right|dz\right|< \log(4\pi r)\int_C |dz|. 
$$
By squeeze theorem and by $\lim_{r\to 0} r\log r=0$ we have
$$\lim_{r\to 0}\int_C \log\left|1-e^{2i\pi z}\right|dz=0.$$

For $z=re^{i\theta }\in C,$ 
$$\left|e^{2i\pi z}\right| =\left|e^{2i\pi r(\cos \theta +i\sin \theta )}\right|=e^{-2\pi r\sin\theta }\le 1
$$
by $\sin \theta \ge 0.$
So $\pi r<\left|1-e^{2i\pi z}\right|<4\pi r$ implies that $$
e^{2i\pi z} \in \{z: |z|\le 1\}\cap \{z: \pi r<|1-z|<4\pi r\}.$$ Hence  $
\left|\arg\left(1-e^{2i\pi z}\right)\right|< \frac{\pi}{2}$
and therefore we have $$
\left|\int_C \arg\left(1-e^{2i\pi z}\right)dz\right|<\frac{\pi}{2}\int_C |dz|\to 0\quad(r\to 0).$$
Now we get $$
\lim_{r\to 0}\int_C \log\left(1-e^{2i\pi z}\right)dz=0.
$$

Comment: How does $|1-e^{2i\pi z}| < 4\pi r$ imply $|arg(1-e^{2i \pi z})| < \arcsin(4\pi r)$?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I edit my answer soon.

Comment: Could you help me understand why $e^{2i \pi z}$ being in the closed unit disc and $\{\pi r< |1-z| < 4 \pi r\}$ imply that the argument of $1-e^{2 i \pi z}$ is $< \pi / 2$?

Comment: So we have $e^{2i \pi z}$ in a unit disc and an annulus centered at $1$, drawing a picture suggests that the maximum angle should be $\pi$ not $\pi/2$. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Since $e^{2i\pi z}$ lies in a unit disc and an annulus centered at $1$, the real part of $1-e^{2i\pi z}$ is positive. So $|\arg(1-e^{2i\pi z})|< \frac{\pi}{2}.$

Comment: The real part being positive means it lies on the first or fourth quadrant, hence the angle could be $\pi/2>$ and $< \pi$?

Comment: How do you define the value of $\arg(1-e^{2i\pi z})$ in the expression $\lim_{r\to 0}\int_C \log(1-e^{2i\pi z}) dz$ ?